# Question about Lie bracket and cross product

Tags: differential-geometry, cross-product

Let $\chi(\mathbb{R^3})$ denote the vector space of all smooth vector fields on $\mathbb{R^3}$, and let $A$ be the subspace of $\chi(\mathbb{R^3})$ spanned by $\{X,Y,Z \}$ where

\begin{align*}
X &= y {\partial \over \partial z}-z {\partial \over \partial y},\\
Y &= z {\partial \over \partial x}-x {\partial \over \partial z},\\
Z &= x {\partial \over \partial y}-y {\partial \over \partial x}.
\end{align*}

The question first ask me to compute the Lie brackets $[X,Y]$,$[Y,Z]$ and $[Z,X]$. Which I did and they are,
\begin{align*}
[X,Y] &= y {\partial \over \partial x}-x {\partial \over \partial y},\\
[Y,Z] &= z {\partial \over \partial y}-y {\partial \over \partial z},\\
[Z,X] &= x {\partial \over \partial z}-z {\partial \over \partial x}.
\end{align*}
Then how can I deduce that there is an isomorphism from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $A$ so that the cross product in $\mathbb{R^3}$ corresponds to the Lie bracket of vector fields.

Comment: The Lie brackets are not zero. If they were, you couldn't conclude what you wanted to conclude.

Comment: Consider some $f \in C^{\infty}$, $[X,Y]f=(XY-YX)f$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @MikeMiller I found the error, which is I forgot to use product rule when taking derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just shown that
$$[X,Y]=-Z,\qquad [Y,Z]=-X,\qquad [Z,X]=-Y.$$
Now it remains to compare this with
$$ \mathbf{e}_x\wedge \mathbf{e}_y =\mathbf{e}_z,\qquad
\mathbf{e}_y\wedge \mathbf{e}_z =\mathbf{e}_x,\qquad
\mathbf{e}_z\wedge \mathbf{e}_x =\mathbf{e}_y.$$

Comment: so the isomorphism is $f(e_z)=-Z$ etc. ?

Comment: @SamC Yes, that's it.